# USB-PD Power negotiation protocol

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

Can a USB-PD UFP port (Monitor) negotiate voltage/power directly from a laptop power supply - not sure if this is called pass-though mode? Or the Monitor can only negotiate USB-PD with the Laptop… and Laptop will negotitate with power supply?

Physical connection is as such

USB-C Port 1 : Connected to Laptop Power supply, say 80W capable
USB-C Port 2 : Connected to Monitor, say requires a sink of 20W.

Comment: Wouldn't the monitor be an upstream-facing port (UFP), not DFP?

Comment: The monitor is downstream but it's usb port is a Upstream port connected to the computers downstream port.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, Monitor would be a UFP only connected to the DFP port 2 of the Laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *transparent* pass-through mode like you describe. PD negotiations are point-to-point.

> Or the Monitor can only negotiate USB-PD with the Laptop… and Laptop will negotitate with power supply?

Exactly.